# Excel - How to look up most recent date data entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Sheet 1 of my spreadsheet is used to show which retail store each member of my team is visiting that week - Team members names on Y axis and days of the week on X axis, then store names in the cells to show where each team member is.

I need to show on sheet 2 the date of the most recent visit. E.g. S05 was visited on the 10th, 11th and 18th Feb. I need column C7 on Sheet 2 to calculate which of the dates on Sheet 1 was the most recent visit.

Comment: `=vlookup(max(date);...)`

Comment: Dates are numbers. You can sort them and look at the top one.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your data?